# Military sci-fi series about a human combat unit on their ship specially bred for their roles

Tags: story-identification, novel, military-sf

Back in the 1980s or 90s, I read the first book in a military science fiction series that dealt with a human combat unit in the far future. The novel mostly took place on their ship, and the humans were genetically bred according to their combat arm (Infantry was big and strong, pilots had fast reflexes, Intel-types had huge brains, etc). The living spaces were communal, their language was coarse, and there was lots of sexual innuendo but no sex. The characters kind of reminded me of Battletech Clans, but there were no Mechs in this book that I can remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You should check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they spark any additional memories you can [edit] into your question.  Do you remember anything about the book itself, like the cover?

Comment: Since we're talking about science fiction, the word "ship" is somewhat ambiguous. Please clarify whether the "ship" is a seagoing vessel, or an airship or spaceship.

Comment: They sound too crude for the [Dorsai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dorsai!), but they are a possibility.

Comment: It is a spaceship. The combat takes place in space and on alien planets.

Comment: Thought I should check back and make sure you're not thinking of Greg Bear's [Hardfought](http://speculiction.blogspot.com/2013/12/review-of-hardfought-by-greg-bear.html).  It's a one-off, not a series, but much of the rest of it kind of matches.